# Assign value of a rosparam to a node param in a launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, shell, rosparam, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to configure the "mongodb_store" as it uses for database_path a directory path that it is stored in a parameter of the ROS server.

The path is stored as "/rosplan/database_path", see below.

```
<launch>
    <param name="/rosplan/domain_path" value="$(find pepito_organizes_boxes)/configuration/domain.pddl" />
    <param name="/rosplan/database_path" value="$(find pepito_organizes_boxes)/common/mongoDB" />
</launch>
```

To achieve this I am calling "rosparama get /rosplan/data_path" in the "command" keyword of "database_path" param" required by "mongodb_store".

```
<launch>    
    <!-- load configuration -->
    <include file="$(find pepito_organizes_boxes)/launch/load_system_config.launch" />

    <!-- knowledge base -->
    <node name="rosplan_knowledge_base" pkg="rosplan_knowledge_base" type="knowledgeBase" respawn="false" output="log" />
    <node name="rosplan_scene_database" pkg="mongodb_store" type="mongodb_server.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
        <param name="database_path" command="/bin/bash -c 'rosparam get /rosplan/database_path' -- " />
    </node>
    <node name="rosplan_scene_message_store" pkg="mongodb_store" type="message_store_node.py" respawn="false" output="log" />
 </launch>
```

It does not work, and output of the console is:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosplan/data_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosplan/database_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosplan/domain_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosplan/planner_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosplan/problem_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosplan/strl_file_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosplan_scene_database/database_path: /home/dieesrod/Wo...
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

process[rosplan_knowledge_base-1]: started with pid [6332]
process[rosplan_scene_database-2]: started with pid [6333]
process[rosplan_scene_message_store-3]: started with pid [6341]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1491130707.159727] Mongo server address: localhost:27017
[INFO] [WallTime: 1491130707.171976] Found MongoDB version 2.4.9
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1491130707.172236] Can't find database at supplied path /home/dieesrod/Workspaces/ROS/indigo/anchoring/src/anchoring_system/experiments/pepito_organize_boxes/common/mongoDB
. If this is a new DB, create it as an empty directory.
[rosplan_scene_database-2] process has died [pid 6333, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/mongodb_store/mongodb_server.py __name:=rosplan_scene_database __log:=/home/dieesrod/.ros/log/17adeaa4-1765-11e7-b57a-a4c49440ffa1/rosplan_scene_database-2.log].
log file: /home/dieesrod/.ros/log/17adeaa4-1765-11e7-b57a-a4c49440ffa1/rosplan_scene_database-2*.log
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1491130717.404485] Can't connect to MongoDB server. Make sure mongodb_store/mongodb_server.py node is started.
```

In fact, when I get the information of "/rosplan/database_path" and "/rosplan_scene_database/database_path" there are some extra spaces in the second one.

```
$ rosparam get /rosplan/database_path
/home/dieesrod/Workspaces/ROS/indigo/anchoring/src/anchoring_system/experiments/pepito_organize_boxes/common/mongoDB

$ rosparam get /rosplan_scene_database/database_path
'/home/dieesrod/Workspaces/ROS/indigo/anchoring/src/anchoring_system/experiments/pepito_organize_boxes/common/mongoDB

  '
```

Do you know why this is happening? And how I could solve this situation?
I am using ROS Indigo running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258438/assign-value-of-a-rosparam-to-a-node-param-in-a-launch-file/) by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-04-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2017-04-05**:
Weird. I also see those spaces when calling `rosparam get`, but only for some parameters. Maybe post a separate question just about those? It seems that if you could figure that out, the rest of the launch file would work.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2017-04-05**:
lindzey@laura-laptop:~$ rosparam dump

```
rosdistro: 'indigo

  '
rosversion: '1.11.20

  '
run_id: 5e4f6c82-19ac-11e7-ad29-001c422b7714
```

**Comment by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) on 2017-04-05**:
Thanks for your answer.

Yes, but I don't know how to remove them. Therefore, I following a workaround, I map the parameters using a python script that I call inside my launch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a workaround for the problem.

I created a python script named as "set_components_config.py", it is responsible of mapping the global parameters to the parameters of each component (e.g. rosplan_scene_database).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy

rospy.set_param("rosplan_scene_database/database_path",
    rospy.get_param("/rosplan/database_path"))

rospy.set_param("rosplan_planning_system/problem_path",
    rospy.get_param("/rosplan/problem_path"))
rospy.set_param("rosplan_planning_system/data_path",
    rospy.get_param("/rosplan/data_path"))
rospy.set_param("rosplan_planning_system/strl_file_path",
    rospy.get_param("/rosplan/strl_file_path"))
```

And this script is called by the launch file after loading the global parameters and before starting the nodes that use them.

```
<launch>
    <!-- load configuration -->
    <include file="$(find pepito_organizes_boxes)/launch/load_system_config.launch" />
    <node name="update_config" pkg="pepito_organizes_boxes" type="set_components_config.py" output="screen" />

    <!-- knowledge base -->
    <node name="rosplan_knowledge_base" pkg="rosplan_knowledge_base" type="knowledgeBase" respawn="false" output="log" />
    <node name="rosplan_scene_database" pkg="mongodb_store" type="mongodb_server.py" respawn="false" output="screen" />
    <node name="rosplan_scene_message_store" pkg="mongodb_store" type="message_store_node.py" respawn="false" output="log" />    
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [dgerod](https://answers.ros.org/users/1843/dgerod/) with karma: 113 on 2017-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0